# python read csv file from command line and write output to output.csv

Tags: python, csv, sys

I am new to python and am trying to read the csv input and output file, scan the input file by each row, and write only those rows to the output file that not not have any special character like '?' or '0'. Below is my code:

```
import csv
import sys
class PreProcessDataSet:
    def preProcessData(self) :
        print ('Enter the input path of the file : ')
        inputFile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
        outputFile = open(sys.argv[2],'wb')
        writer = csv.writer(outputFile)
        i = 0
        for row in csv.reader(inputFile):
            if (row[i]!="0" or row[i] != "?"):
                writer.writerow(row)
                i=i+1
                print row
```

This code does not give any output. Can someone please help me out with it ?

Comment: You define a class here. Maybe you did not mean to, but I'm not seeing an actual call to it. Are you missing it? If not, can you share it?
Furthermore, kinda weird to call sys.argv[1] like that. Did you mean to read it from the console?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition `if (row[i]!="0" or row[i] != "?"):` is always true. Suppose it is 0, then it certainly isn't ? so one of the `or` conditions always passes. This code should print rows until it crashes for other reasons (see below). So, I think your first problem is that you are not actually calling the method.

Next, you are incrementing the column indexer `i` once per row, so it will read cell 0 on the first row, cell 1 on the second row, ... and eventually you will get an index error when `i` grows larger than the number of columns. Its not really doing what you want either, its only checking one cell per row.

You can use set intersections to find out if a restricted character is in any of the cells. Its not clear to me whether the cell has to exactly equal one of the restricted characters or not, so I wrote this example to find any occurrence in the row by joining the row to a single string for checking.

```
import csv
import sys

class PreProcessDataSet:
    def preProcessData(self) :
        special_chars = set('?0')
        # Don't tease the user with prompts that don't work!
        # print ('Enter the input path of the file : ')
        inputFile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
        outputFile = open(sys.argv[2],'wb')
        print "Converting", inputFile, "to", outputFile
        writer = csv.writer(outputFile)
        for row in csv.reader(inputFile):
            if not set(''.join(row)) & special_chars:
                writer.writerow(row)
                print row


obj = PreProcessDataSet()
obj.preProcessData()
```

A sample run:

```
~/tmp $ cat infile.csv
one,two,three
0,four,five
six?,seven,eight
nine,ten,eleven
~/tmp $ python test.py infile.csv outfile.csv
Converting <open file 'infile.csv', mode 'rb' at 0x7f9d4d0165d0> to <open file 'outfile.csv', mode 'wb' at 0x7f9d4d016660>
['one', 'two', 'three']
['nine', 'ten', 'eleven']
~/tmp $ cat outfile.csv
one,two,three
nine,ten,eleven
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Also the restricted characters 0 or ? if present should not be written to the output file. Also, this code does not really write to the output file. Could you please help me out?

Comment: It works for me. You `print ('Enter the input path of the file : ')` but then get your file names from `sys.argv`. Maybe the files just aren't going where you think they should. I'll update the example with more prints.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps!